# Update database 10 minutes after an action

Tags: php, mysql

Currently I have a button that a logged in user can press every **10** minutes by taking the current time + 10 minutes and inserting that in the database.

```
public function setCooldown($address){
    $extra = strtotime("+ 10 minutes");
    $cooldown =  date("h:i:s", $extra);

    $query = $this->pdo->prepare("UPDATE users SET cooldown = '$cooldown'     
                                  WHERE address = '$address'");

    if($query->execute()){
        return true;
    }else return false;
}
```

It then checks if 10 minutes have passed using the following if-statement:

```
    if(strtotime($cooldown) >= time()){
        return true;
    }else return false;
```

`$cooldown`fetches the cooldown from the database.

**The issue:**

- If you click the button at **12:55** (AM/PM), the `cooldown` will be set to **1:05** (AM/PM).

Since 12:55 >= 1:05, there will be no cooldown.

- If you click the button at **12:45** (AM/PM) the `cooldown`will be set to **12:55** (AM/PM)

And if you then forget to click for the next, let's say 10 minutes after the cooldown wears off, the `time()`will be 1:05, and the cooldown will be **nearly 12 hours**!

**Question:** How can I set the cooldown to 10 minutes no matter the time of the day?

**Notes:**

- `cooldown` is set as varchar in my database

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Store a timestamp in the database, not a string.

Comment: Store cooldown time with datetime or timestamp ( 2016-01-30 01:05:00 ) in database. Comparing only time is different from date time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just checked your code. you should use 24h format for the date('H:i:s'). Hope this will solve your problem.
please check below links:-

http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php

http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_date.asp